# Pb with stored statement

Tags: mysql, variables, store

I would like to pre-execute a query and store the result in @query:

```
BEGIN 

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(50); 
SET @table = 'top20-img-link';
SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT model FROM ', @table);
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `TABLE1`;
CREATE TABLE `TABLE1` 
AS (
SELECT *,
CASE 

WHEN (family1='top20-img-link') THEN @query
WHEN (family2='top20-img-link') THEN @query2           
WHEN (family2='top20-img-link') THEN @query3
END prod1
```

ETC.

But I get a  syntax error message at line 3. I haven't been able to find an example that fits my need, so please help me.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: "You have an error of syntax at line 3" (which starts with 'Declare')

Answer (score 0):

If you use @ with variable it will work as user defined variable in MySQL, 
Hence, "No need to declare user defined variable." please remove first line `DECLARE @query VARCHAR(50);`.

When you use user variable, please keep this in mind:

For **SET**, either `=` or `:=` can be used as the assignment operator.

You can also assign a value to a user variable in statements other than SET. In this case, the assignment operator must be `:=` and not `=` because the latter is treated as the comparison operator `=` in non-SET statements

Please refer this two link to understand how you can user [Local Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html) and [User-Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) in MySQL.

Comment: I removed `DECLARE @query VARCHAR(50);` but still get a syntax error at first line.

Comment: please add full query related to create table,  it seems incomplete. where do you get query1, query2 parameter from ? and If you remove first it will be solved issue related with 'declare'. if you still get any issue with this please add issue description. so we can get better idea of issue.